# Should I use the word “tomorning”?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have never used the word *tomorning*.   Can I use it like *tonight*, instead of *today morning*?

Comment: You can use it, but few people will understand.

Comment: Emmanuel Angelo.R, no. "*Tomorning*" is not a genuine word or well known in the English-speaking world. It's just wrong. So is "*today morning*". Both of these are likely to cause this kind of reaction in native speakers http://www.newjerseyhunter.com/forums/attachments/18048d1400114999-hollow-point-bullets-confused-meme.jpg and http://makeameme.org/media/created/Huh-7fz21k.jpg

Comment: If this is your reaction what was the reaction when first they used the word 'quiz'. We can be trendsetters.

Comment: Emmanuel Angelo.R, what do you mean?

Comment: There is no such term as *today morning*.  One says ***this** morning* instead.

Answer (score 1):

As a slang expression I think you can use it .  [Tomorning](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tomorning):

> Shortened version of "tomorrow morning," but its use is also similar to that of tonight. Can also be used in the sense of "this morning," although such use is less common.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tomorning%2C%20Tomorning&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctomorning%3B%2Cc0) shows little evidence of its usage.

Comment: Yea thanks Josh61 for additional clarification with Ngram.

Comment: But people may not understand if you do.

Comment: Yes, as with many other slag expressions. But I think OP is aware of it.

Comment: "*Can* use it", perhaps but I think this answer should carry a warning. It's not just that people might not understand. They might understand *wrongly*, given that the primary meaning in your quote is different to that intended.

Answer (score 1):

There is Scottish phrase for *tomorrow morning* which is

> the morn's morn.

I'm not sure how widespread that phrase is outside Scotland,  not very I would think.

I can't add a reference, I'm on a tiny keyboarded device, but a search for the phrase and Scottish should get results .

I can't think of any other "English" terms that mean *tomorrow morning* in common use anywhere. *Tomorning* sounds like it ought be used more often : )

Comment: The Scottish *morn’s morn* reminds me of the Spanish *mañana por la mañana* (which you sometimes hear “in English” amongst bilingual code-switchers).  The Scottish version definitely wins out for being only a quarter as many syllables. :)  Dang it, in this font, *morn’s morn* looks like one’s maternal grandmother.